# SSRS and Render and Stream info

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am porting a web forms application to mvc. The forms app made heavy use of the ReportViewer control which does not extend well in the mvc world. I have started from scratch. The only properties I can not reliably replicate without a custom renderer is Page Count and Total Page Count. How to get these value using the ReportExecution? I am really hesitant to invest time/resources into a custom renderer. The only thing I can think of and do not like is setting the DeviceInfo.Section and catch the exception when it is not in range. The report is being rendered in HTML40 format.

Comment: I would be interested to know why you have started from scratch.

Comment: It is a challenge. I have a base view that can inject the report as html. I am using razor @RenderSections to render derivate report params from the base view to derivate views(BaseView->DerivedView). On the Ajax Postback I call a controller method calculating the params and sends back the url. In the base class I catch that url and load it using a format option to either load html in in a div or output as file. It is a three hop process to catch a parameter change and calculate the url for rendering :( I send in html|pdf|excel to the final render method to return file or html.

Answer (score 1):

Continue to use the ReportViewer control embedded in an .aspx page, and create an MVC route to this page:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
          "Reports",
          "Reports/{folder}/{name}",
          "~/Reports/default.aspx",
          false,
          new RouteValueDictionary(
              new { folder = "", name = "", controller = "", action = "" }),

          new RouteValueDictionary(
              new { constraint = new ReportConstraint() })
          );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have stated that I am attempting to render the report in a partial view where the report content url is posted back in an async fashion and the html element is being fed from that url. I am afraid this cant be duplicated with reportviewer?